# Hypothesis to get if The Samsung Average customer satisfaction score is minimum 75%

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, statistics

This is a peer comparison project. Suppose that you are working for Samsung in customer experience management team. The idea is to regularly monitor the customer satisfaction levels and peer company moves. The competitor company is Apple. The objective is to test two main hypothesis.

1. The Samsung Average customer satisfaction score is minimum 75%.
2. The overall average satisfaction score of Samsung is same as Apple. There is no significant difference in the satisfaction scores
   • It might be possible that both hypothesis are correct, one of them is correct or both of them are wrong. Perform the relevant testing to verify these assumptions
   The data is collected for 100 Samsung customers and 100 Apple customers. Their satisfaction scores are recorded. The sample represent the data and it is unbiased.

The Samsung Average customer satisfaction score is minimum 75%.
code - stats.ttest_1samp(a = Customer['Samsung Score'], popmean = 75)
Is the above code correct to get p value?
For second question my code is
cust = stats.ttest_ind(a=Customer['Samsung Score'], b=Customer['Apple_Score'], equal_var=True)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to calculate 75% of the customer satisfaction score of Samsung using the quantile method and use that value as popmean in stats.ttest_1samp, instead of 75.